# How to cast SQLEqCondition<Integer> into Integer in jooq?

Tags: java, sql, collections, integer, jooq

In `Jooq`.

```
private SQLEqCondition<Integer> validRSN= new SQLEqCondition<>(MyTable.MYTABLE.Valid_RSN);
```

This is my method. It fetches a `validRSN` in the table:

Here's example:

```
public boolean validRSN(){
        Integer count = Transaction.current().selectFrom(MyTable.MYTABLE).where(MyTable.MYTABLE.Valid_RSN.eq(DSL.cast(validRSN, MyTable.MYTABLE.Valid_RSN))).fetchCount();
        return count > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

But it return  false.

Please tell me how to cast it?

Comment: Please explain where this `SQLEqCondition` is defined.  I can't find it in the JOOQ javadocs.

Comment: SQLEqCondition<T> extends AbstractSQLCondition<T>

Comment: And where is THAT class defined.  Please provide the FQN and the link to the javadocs.

Comment: I have to agree with others. This question is currently not answerable. Please provide all information needed to understand the problem you had been having.